# Under what conditions isTransactionEnd in change events come as False?

Tags: streaming-api, platform-event

I am doing the [Subscribe to an Event Channel](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/subscribe-to-events) trail to learn about change events and confused about `isTransactionEnd` field that is returned in the header.

Documentation [Change Event Header Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_event_fields_header.htm) say

> Indicates whether this change is the final change in a transaction.

Can someone explain or give an example of when `isTransactionEnd` comes as false in change events?

Comment: Great find. I have added details on this field based on a quick test. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick test to understand this based on what is mentioned in [Learn Change Data Capture Characteristics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/learn-change-data-capture-characteristics) where it discusses Transaction-Related Header Fields:

> The sequenceNumber field identifies the sequence of the change within a transaction. The sequence number is useful for operations that include multiple steps, such as lead conversion or creating related records in an after insert  Apex trigger. And the isTransactionEnd field indicates whether the change is the last step in the sequence. We recommend that you replicate all the changes in one transaction as a single commit in your system.

With what is mentioned above and the test below, what I could figure out that if you are trying to replicate the data at an external system, you will need to ensure that all **related** entities (not specifically a relationship field viz., lookup/M-D but even if you create an unrelated record say in after trigger of an object) in one single transaction; are replicated as well. And the header fields here will ensure that you are receiving the data in entirety and that nothing is missed. It depends on the order of events generated. E.g., if you are using an after trigger on ObjA and creating an ObjB record, then the flag will be false on event received for ObjA but not on ObjB.

---

I performed a Lead Conversion and was able to see that if you you are only subscribed to an Account, you will receive a response where `isTransactionEnd` is `false`. The response looked something as below:

```
...
"ChangeEventHeader": {
  "isTransactionEnd": false, // notice this is false
  "commitNumber": xxxx,
  "commitUser": "xxxx",
  "sequenceNumber": 1, // the sequence number is 1, means there are other as well
  "entityName": "Account",
  "changeType": "CREATE",
  "recordIds": [
    "001XYZ"
  ]
...
```

And when I picked up the events from Lead (or subscribed to All Change Events), I could see the response as below, where the `isTransactionId` was now set to `true`. Also notice that it consists of the converted account id and the `sequenceNumber` which is one up than what was received earlier.

```
...
"Status": "Closed - Converted",
    "ConvertedAccountId": "001XYZ", // this is the account id above
    "ConvertedDate": "2019-04-23",
    "IsConverted": true,
    "ChangeEventHeader": {
      "isTransactionEnd": true, // now this is true, signifying this is complete
      "commitNumber": xxxx,
      "commitUser": "xxxx",
      "sequenceNumber": 2, // and the sequence number is one greater than earlier
      "entityName": "Lead",
      "changeType": "UPDATE",
...
```

Comment: I did a similar scenario like this: on After insert trigger of Account object, I am inserting a Employee__c record and subscribed to Employee change events. I receive the Employee event and it still has `isTransactionEnd` as true. What am I missing here?

Comment: Ok. so if I establish a lookup or master-detail relationship between Employee and Account objects, you think I will be able to replicate? I just want to try a different scenario than what is given in the docs :)

Comment: So I created a lookup relationship on Employee__c object pointing to Account object and from after insert event of Account object, creating a Employee__c record. I subscribed to only Employee change events. Still receiving `isTransactionEnd` as True.

Comment: I subscribed to both Account and Employee and now for Account change events, it is coming back as False and for Employee change events, it is coming as true. So, I believe, because the Account is the first DML happening in the transaction and Employee is the last DML in transaction so it is coming as true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92809/discussion-between-javanoob-and-jayant-das).